# Python IDLE: unable to input Chinese characters

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-idle

I have problem entering Chinese characters in the Python IDLE, both shell and editor. IDLE accepts Chinese characters input at the beginning, but for a very short while, it stops accepting Chinese characters.

I tried to restart IDLE, and the same thing happened: it allows Chinese character inputting may for one or two sentences, but after that, it stops accepting Chinese character (English characters appear during Chinese character inputting). Can anyone help?

The environment:
Ubuntu: 14.04
Python: 3.4.0
IDLE: 3.4.0
TK: 8.6.1
IBus: 1.5.5 (with "Chewing" input method)

Comment: Idle uses tkinter, which wraps the tck/tk gui framework.  Tk is responsible for handling keystrokes and putting chars into a Text widget.  Idle mostly ignores the actual text, but sends it on to Python to execute.  So I am 99% sure the problem with tk and the input method.  To be sure, run `python -c "import tkinter as tk;root = tk.Tk();text = tk.Text(root);text.pack();root.mainloop()"` (one line, without any linefeeds added by SO) to get a pure tk Text widget and enter into that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your command. Everything runs fine at the beginning. However, after I do other things, such as switching to other windows do something and coming back, it's broken (only English letters show up). This is the same as in the IDLE editor: it starts alright, but after I run the program and try to edit the program again, it's broken. TK seems very unstable.